# Dotnet Maui Shell Navigate Tab Page

Tags: c#, maui

I would like to create a data entry page in my Maui Shell App.  Users select the option from Flyout menu then it show a screen to list the available records to edit.  When user select one of the row from the list or press the Add button, the other screen (tabbed page) will show to let user input the data.

I create a FlyoutItem with multiple pages in AppShell.xaml with FlyoutItemIsVisual="False" (user cannot select the edit page directly from Flyout menu).  In the list screen I called GotoAsync to navigate the Edit page but failed because "Relative routing with Shell elements is not supported".

AppShell.xaml:

```
<FlyoutItem Title="List">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:ListPage}"/>
</FlyoutItem>

<FlyoutItem FlyoutItemIsVisible="False" Route="EditPageRoute">
    <page:EditPage Title="General Info"/>
    <page:RemarkEditPage Title="Remarks"/>
</FlyoutItem>
```

ListPage.xaml.cs:

```
private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SElectionChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    var rec = r.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as TableRow;
    var _param = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "Id", rec.Id }
    }
    if (rec != null) await Shell.Current.GotoAsync("EditPageRoute", _prarm);
}
```

I try other options that GotoAsync only accept if change the route name to "///EditPageRoute" and the edit page can be display but it replace the current navigation stack that cannot go back to list page after edit.

How can I append the tabbed page to the navigation stack either define the routing in xaml or code behind?  It seems the Routing.RegisterRoute method in C# is not accept a FlyoutItem and it cannot register a multi tab page.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each tab you see has its own navigation stack. As you have noticed, using "///" makes you jump from tab to tab, but that is it. You can go to ///cats open, /list and /details, then go to ///dogs, and the stack in your ///cats tab will still be saved.

You can do ///cats then /dogs.

If you want to do ///cats///dogs, you will have to write a lot of navigation code on your own.

Technically, nothing is stopping you from recording Navigation events in your shell,  adding handler to your "back" and making custom page header.